# double pointer output explanation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Could you explain how the output is `-4`? I think `++pp;` is UB but not sure. Your explanation will really help in the way of understanding. Could be there any difference of outputs in big-endian or little-endian machine?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[] = { -1, -2, -3, -4 };
int b[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

int main(void)
{
    int *p[] = { a, b };
    int **pp = p;
    printf("a=%p, b=%p, p=%p, pp=%p\n", (void*)a, (void*)b, (void*)p, (void*)pp);
    ++pp;
    printf("p=%p, pp=%p *pp=%p\n", (void*)p, (void*)pp, (void*)*pp);
    ++*pp;
    printf("p=%p, pp=%p *pp=%p\n", (void*)p, (void*)pp, (void*)*pp);
    ++**pp;

    printf("%d\n", (++**pp)[a]);
}
```

My output:

```
a=0x107121040, b=0x107121050, p=0x7ffee8adfad0, pp=0x7ffee8adfad0
p=0x7ffee8adfad0, pp=0x7ffee8adfad8 *pp=0x107121050
p=0x7ffee8adfad0, pp=0x7ffee8adfad8 *pp=0x107121054
-4
```

[Ideone output](http://www.ideone.com/6xzVQT)

Comment: The best way to understand this type problem is to take out a sheet of paper and pencil and lay out where `p` and `pp` point for each given line in your code. `p` is an *array of pointers to* `int` initialized to `{a, b}`, pursuant to [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3). `pp` is a *pointer to pointer to* `int` initialized to `p`. Advancing `++p` does what? (it advances a pointer). Where did the pointer point? (`a`). What is the next pointer (`b`);, and so on...

Comment: The other thing to remember is that when an array name is used as a pointer, it decays to the address of the first element of the array. So `int *pp = p;` is equivalent to `int *pp = &p[0];`.

Comment: After `pp++`, it now points to `&p[1]`.

Comment: Also understand `(++**pp)[a]` is equivalent to `a[++**pp]`. (which is `a[3]` in your case) The key is [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) (pay attention to the **"Associativity"**)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the name of an array (in most contexts), it decays to a pointer to its first element.  That means that `int* p = a;` and `int* p = &a[0];` are exactly the same.

So to understand what happens in this case, just walk through step by step.  At the point of your first `printf` call, things look like this:

```
 pp            p           a
+-------+     +------+     +----+----+----+----+
|   +--------->   +--------> -1 | -2 | -3 | -4 |
+-------+     |      |     +----+----+----+----+
              |      |
              +------+     b
              |      |     +----+----+----+----+
              |  +---------> 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
              |      |     +----+----+----+----+
              +------+
```

`pp` points to the first element of `p`, which is a pointer to the first element of `a`.

Now, when you increment `pp`, it changes to point to the second element of `p`, which is a pointer to the first element of `b`:

```
 pp            p           a
+-------+     +------+     +----+----+----+----+
|   +   |     |   +--------> -1 | -2 | -3 | -4 |
+---|---+     |      |     +----+----+----+----+
    |         |      |
    |         +------+     b
    |         |      |     +----+----+----+----+
    +--------->  +---------> 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
              |      |     +----+----+----+----+
              +------+
```

You then increment `*pp`.  Since `*pp` is a pointer to the first element of `b`, that pointer is incremented to point to the second element of `b`:

```
 pp            p           a
+-------+     +------+     +----+----+----+----+
|   +   |     |   +--------> -1 | -2 | -3 | -4 |
+---|---+     |      |     +----+----+----+----+
    |         |      |
    |         +------+     b
    |         |      |     +----+----+----+----+
    +--------->      |     | 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
              |   +  |     +----+-^--+----+----+
              +---|--+            |
                  +---------------+
```

Then you increment `**pp`.  At this point `pp` is a pointer to the second element of `p`, so `*pp` is a pointer to the second element of `b`.  That means `**pp` names the second element of `b`.  You increment that from `1` to `2`:

```
 pp            p           a
+-------+     +------+     +----+----+----+----+
|   +   |     |   +--------> -1 | -2 | -3 | -4 |
+---|---+     |      |     +----+----+----+----+
    |         |      |
    |         +------+     b
    |         |      |     +----+----+----+----+
    +--------->      |     | 0  | 2  | 2  | 3  |
              |   +  |     +----+-^--+----+----+
              +---|--+            |
                  +---------------+
```

Now, lets dissect `(++**pp)[a]`.  `++**pp` is the same as before, so the second element of `b` gets incremented to `3`.

Now, for any pointer `ptr` and integer `n`, `ptr[n]` is the same as `*(ptr + n)`.  Since addition is commutative, `ptr + n` is the same as `n + ptr`.  That means `ptr[n]` is the same as `n[ptr]`.

Putting these together, that means that `(++**pp)[a]` is the same as `3[a]`, which is the same as `a[3]`.  `a[3]` is `-4`, hence your result.

Comment: Diagrams alone are worth the UV. (a picture is worth 1000 words...)

Answer (score 1):

Remember the definition of the subscription operator `[]`, e.g. as defined in [this](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2) online C standard draft:

> **6.5.2.1 Array subscripting**
>
> 2) ... The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is
>   identical to (*((E1)+(E2))). ...

It says that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)).Then it becomes clear that `(++**pp)[a]` is the same as `*((++**pp)+(a))`, which again is the same as `*((a)+(++**pp))`, which consequently reads as `a[(++**pp)]`. The value of `++**pp` is `3` then, and `a[3]` is `-4`.

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to understand this if you express all the array names in expressions as their decayed values. `arrayName` as a pointer becomes `&arrayName[0]`. So after all the initializations, you have:

```
a[0] = -1, a[1] = -2, a[2] = -3, a[3] = -4
b[0] = 0, b[1] = 1, b[2] = 2, b[3] = 3
p[0] = &a[0], p[1] = &b[0]
pp = &p[0]
```

Incrementing a pointer makes it point to the next array element, so after `++pp` we now have

```
pp = &p[1]
```

`++*pp` dereferences `pp`, so it's equivalent to `++p[1]`, so now we have

```
p[1] = &b[1]
```

`++**pp` dereferences this twice, so it's equivalent to `++b[1]`, so now we have

```
b[1] = 2
```

Finally, we have the really confusing expression `(++**pp)[a]`. `++**pp` again increments `b[1]`, so its value is now `3`, and that value replaces that expression, so it's equivalent to `3[a]`. This might look like nonsense (`3` isn't an array, how can you index it?), but it turns out that in C, `x[y] == y[x]` because of the way indexing is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic. So `3[a]` is the same as `a[3]`, and the last line prints `-4`.